# Id como parámetro de función

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una función que como parámetro de cabecera, recibe el id de un input text.

```
<input id="cDni" type="text" name="dni" maxlenght="20" size="20">
```

La función:

```
function nuevaFC(id){
    var nFil = document.createElement("tr");
    var nCol;
    var a ="'#'+'id'";

    nuevaColumna = document.createElement("td");
    nuevaColumna.innerHTML = document.querySelector(a).value;
    nuevaFila.appendChild(nuevaColumna);
}
```

Trato de concatenar #, con el parámetro de cabecera, pero de todas las formas que he probado, no acepta ninguna.
¿Alguna idea sobre cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Probaste con  `var a ='#' + id;`?

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios problemas en tu código.

Por una parte el constructor del selector que debería ser concatenar (`+`) el string `'#'` con la variable `id`.

Por otro lado tienes un problema con los nombres de las variables: las declaras con un nombre y las usas con otro.

Por último no añades la fila creada al DOM.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo con esos errores corregidos:

```js
function nuevaFC(id){
  var nuevaFila = document.createElement("tr");
  var a ='#'+ id;

  var nuevaColumna = document.createElement("td");
  nuevaColumna.innerHTML = document.querySelector(a).value;
  nuevaFila.appendChild(nuevaColumna);
  
  // Añadir la fila
  document.getElementById('tabla').appendChild(nuevaFila);
}

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click',
  function() {nuevaFC('cDni'); });
```

```html
<input id="cDni" type="text" name="dni" maxlenght="20" size="20">
<button id="add">Añadir</button>
<table id="tabla"></table>
```

Comment: gracias x tu respuesta. Sigue apareciendo el mismo error, asociado a la fila "nuevaColumna.innerHTML = document.querySelector(a).value;". Cannot read property value of null...

Comment: Habría que ver el código completo y cuándo y cómo llamas a la función. Ten en cuenta que no se llame a la función antes de crear el elemento. Como puedes ver en el ejemplo debería funcionar